# Declare Record with External Data Field?

Tags: external-data-column

2 Part Question:

If I delcare a record on a item that has a External Data field will that field change if the column in that table is updated or will it remain static?

And if it does change, is there a way to look at external data and then put in my fields as a string value so it cant change?

Answer (score 0):

I can reply to part 2:
You can attach a workflow to your list, then read the value inserted into the external data field and copy it into another field